# jQuery floating box on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This jQuery code which makes a div float when you scroll. It's a side menu with questions, if you klick a question you're sent to the corresponding question and answer on the page. On smaller screen eg. iPhone X in landscape mode, the box scrolls past the bottom of page and extends it - creating a never ending page.

```
jQuery(function() {

var $sidebar   = jQuery("#questions-menu"), 
    $window    = jQuery(window),
    offset     = $sidebar.offset(),
    topPadding = 20;

$window.scroll(function() {
    if ($window.scrollTop() > offset.top) {
        $sidebar.stop().animate({
            marginTop: $window.scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
        });
    } else {
        $sidebar.stop().animate({
            marginTop: 0
        });
    }
});

});
```

I've been trying to get it to stop following the scoll once you reach the bottom of the page without success.

Comment: Add your html and create snippet if possible.

Comment: I've seen that effect many times and I find it annoying. Why not use fixed element for the sidebar?

Comment: Depending on your structure but you could possibly solve this with pure css  I would guess. `position: sticky; top: [some value]`, it does make it harder to help you without the proper "material" provided, could you provide html/css? Note, `sticky` is not supported in ie11 <, for me (generally the industry) is way past making "nice to have" features work for ie.